# Python code change does not take effect

Tags: python

I'm new to `Python` Programming. I have downloaded a python project from internet. Now I want to change a few line of code on the downloaded project. I am using `Python` IDLE on mac `OSX` to change the code. But even after changing the code when i execute the program it runs old code! How do i make changes to code in such a way that it reflects on the code when i run next time.

Here is the Structure how my project works.

File1 somethingone.py
File2 somethingtwo.py <= here i'm importing somethingone.py

I'm executing this on terminal => python somethingtwo.py

EDIT : 
here is a function in somethingone.py before edit

```
def download_photo(self, media_id, path='foldername/', filename=None, 
    description=False):
    delay.small_delay(self)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    if description:
        media = self.get_media_info(media_id)[0]
        caption = media['caption']['text']
        with open('{path}{0}_{1}.txt'.format(media['user']['username'], media_id, path=path), 'w') as f:
            f.write(caption)
    photo = super(self.__class__, self).downloadPhoto(media_id, filename, False, path)
    if photo:
        return photo
    self.logger.info("Media with %s is not %s ." % (media_id, 'downloaded'))
    return False
```

AFTER edit

```
def download_photo(self, media_id, path='foldername/', filename=None, 
    description=False):
    delay.small_delay(self)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    if description:
        media = self.get_media_info(media_id)[0]
        caption = ""
        with open('{path}{0}_{1}.txt'.format(media['user']['username'], media_id, path=path), 'w') as f:
            f.write(caption)
    photo = super(self.__class__, self).downloadPhoto(media_id, filename, False, path)
    if photo:
        return photo
    self.logger.info("Media with %s is not %s ." % (media_id, 'downloaded'))
    return False
```

Here is a function from somethingtwo.py where above function is used:

```
def myfunc(obj, new_media_id, path=POSTED_MEDIAS):
    if exists_in_posted_medias(new_media_id, path):
        obj.logger.warning("Media {0} was uploaded earlier".format(new_media_id))
        return False
    photo_path = obj.download_photo(new_media_id, description=True)
    return photo_path
```

Comment: Could you show us examples of code in `somethingone.py` and `somethingtwo.py` and what change you do?

Comment: Please check the EDIT

Comment: Okay and what is in `somethingtwo.py`?

Comment: @TerryA Updated

Comment: What is `obj` here

Comment: I can code. I just want to know why is it executing old code even after Saving changes to the old code?

Comment: And how do i execute new code after saving changes?

Comment: Have you just tried adding a simple print('Hello world') to make sure it isn't executing but doing something other than what you expect?

Comment: Yes i tried. But still its executing old code in Terminal. So the "HelloWorld" is not printed

Comment: Delete any .pyc files in your directory.  Make sure you are modifying the same file you are trying to run (check full paths).  Make sure you are saving the file in IDLE before executing it.  Add a print statement (not a logger function call) at the top of the code to see if it runs.  Try running it in IDLE with 'run module'.  Create a brand new python file in the same directory in IDLE with only a print statement and see if THAT runs.  It's going to end up being something simple.

Comment: I have created a new file coded to print "Hello World" and it works perfectly.
But when i edit the imported file and then run my script, it does not take effect